# How to avoid large actions classes with Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony1

working on a project at the minute and don't feel the code is as well structured/decoupled/maintainable as it should be.

I think the main problem is using one actions class to do the brunt of the work of my system. But what are the alternatives? My other modules are pretty basic and separate.

Should the model contain more business logic that I have in my controller (at the minute the model file for the actions class in question is more or less empty, the Table model file doesn't have much either).

I was reading http://www.slideshare.net/nperriault/30-symfony-best-practices which has some good points, one of them being avoiding having large actions classes but doesn't really tell you how it should be done.

Should I break up my actions class and have different files in /apps/frontend/module/myModule/lib/. ?

The problem is I have another actions class that has to reuse some functionality from the class mentioned above... I really don't want to have duplicate code an am getting into a bit of a mess.

Some general pointers would be great, thanks

Comment: Why don't you publish your action class here, so we can give some practical advice?

Answer (score 1):

You can either keep all actions in one file, or put each action in its own file.

So, either

```
class mymoduleActions extends sfActions
{
  public function executeIndex($request)
  {
    // ...
  }

  public function executeList($request)
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

or

```
class indexAction extends sfAction
{
  public function execute($request)
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

plus

```
class listAction extends sfAction
{
  public function execute($request)
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

It's all [in the documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_sub_alternative_action_class_syntax). You should then put reusable code in a parent `XYZAction` class that both action classes can extend.

Answer (score 0):

You can always put code in `apps/frontend/lib`. Create classes that have the code that may be re-used and you can just call the methods from within your actions to avoid duplication